# How to send a source code using JSON in java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to send a C/C++ code from a servlet using JSON object

```
        //server end
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        JSONObject jsonCode = new JSONObject();

        json.put("code", code); //this have a C/C++ code

        json.put("success", true);

        //client end

        function getCode(pointer)
        {

            var id = pointer.data.id;
            var json = { "id" : id };
                     $.ajax({
                "url" : "getCode",
                        "data" : json,
                                 "type" : "POST",

                                          "success" : function(data)
                {

                    alert(data.success); //undefined why ?
                    console.log(data);
                    if (!data.success) {

                        alert('code cannot be fetched');
                    }
                }
                ,
                    "error" : function(xhr, status, error)
                {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(xhr.responseText); //this is giving me the JSON ??

                    editor.setValue(xhr.responseText);
                }
```

But instead of function against success,error function is getting called ?
Please help me out

Edit:This is a sample json which is my trying to send

```
    enter code here
    {"code":#include<iostream>

    class bbb{

    bbb(int array[12][12]=NULL){


    }

    };

    class aaa{

    };
    int func(int=12,int=123);
    int func(int x,int y){
    std::cout<<x<<y<<std::endl;
    }


    int main()
    {
    int array[12];
    int x=12;

    func(13);

    if(1==x){

    }
    //add your code here
    return 0;
    }
    ,"success":true}
```

Now i have also used RestMan to test it, and it appears as if JSON gets broken when code is included.Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Sounds like your server is returning the correct body with an incorrect status code. Please ascertain that the data is returned with `HTTP 200`.

Comment: can you post your logs?

Comment: It is returning 200 as status

Comment: are you sending success parameter in response from server? as you are checking  alert(data.success);

Comment: Yes I'm sending it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON file containing the code is invalid JSON.

In a valid JSON file a string value must be surrounded by double quotes ("value") and line breaks must be escaped with \n. Don't use JSON and instead send the code separately or use a JSON encoder which escapes reserved characters.

A syntactically valid JSON file should look somewhat like this:

```
{
    "code":"#include<iostream>\n\nclass bbb{\n\nbbb(int array[12][12]=NULL){\n\n\n}...",
    "success":true
}
```